# append json objects contents to output in div elem as a list

Tags: javascript

Currently I have it outputting in my `console.log` but I'd like to keep very similar syntax and output the same json data into a div on the page named `id="results"`

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
       // console.log(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

**update** - So I actually got it to print, but it only prints latest; I'd like to print all in list format with accessible selectors on each list item so I can manipulate later.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
```

The above works, but only displays latest. I want to display all, in list format.

---

**update for clarity:** when I mention list format. I mean to essentially record all entered form data as growing list `<li></li>`: Expanded question moved here: [save javascript cookie from all inserted web form values output in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193613/save-javascript-cookie-from-all-inserted-web-form-values-output-in-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just text once it is stringified

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var data = $(this).serializeObject()),
      stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
   $('#results').text(stringData );
   return false;
});
```

If you want to prettify the json use `JSON.stringify(data, null,4)`;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean about list format, and latest etc..
But if you want to see the JSON in a nice way in the browser the following might work for you.

```js
$('[data-id=showme]').click(function () {
  var someObj = $('[data-id=form]').serializeObject();
  $('[data-id=result]').text(
    JSON.stringify(someObj, null, '  ')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-serialize-object/2.5.0/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>


<form data-id="form">
  <input name="test" value="test">
  <input name="xyz" value="xyz">
</form>

<button data-id="showme">Show me</button>

<pre data-id="result">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain js? that is odd..because you are alredy using jQuery!!!

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {

    var value = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());

    documnet.getElementById('the id of your element').innerHTML = value;

    return false;

   });
});
```

or simply:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {

    var value = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());

    $('#someElementId').text(value);

    return false;

   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, was still working on the question.. So I actually got it to print, but it only prints latest; I'd like to print all in list format with accessible selectors on each.