# save javascript cookie from all inserted web form values output in div

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a very small html web form. I'd like to grab all entered form contents, after the user fills out the form and then clicks my `.add` button. I'm trying to set a cookie to achieve this. I would like form's contents to appear within my `.results` div after *each* time it has been filled out / clicked.

Below is my progress, which I believe is getting close:

```
    $(function () {
      $(".add").click(function () {

            addContent('results', document.form.addContent.value); setCookie('content', document.form.addContent.value, 7);

          // $('.results').html($('.results').html()+"<br/>"+form.html());
      });
    });
    function addContent('results', content) {
         document.getElementByClassName('results').innerHTML = content;
    }
```

---

```
            <form id="form" name="form">....

<!-- simple html web form, 4-6 fields -->

            <button class="add">add</button>

            </form>

    <div class="results"></div>....
```

---

*Currently nothing rendering / outputting in `.results` div.

as well as receiving this error in console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string***.

---

**Update:**

Within this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5s7cj6n/2/) is my full code. Although jsfiddle is outputting it's own environment errors now with 'please user POST method' etc. I don't get anything like that at on my actual server, but at least seeing the full code may help paint a better picture of the problem / goal / question.